# Why is re-run only updating props one time with react-hooks-testing-libary?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a hook with `useEffect`. I noticed that `useEffect` is not being run more than twice because after one `rerender` call with different data, subsequent calls do not get the updated data.

```
export default function(lookForUsername) {
  const [dashboardHref, setDashboardHref] = useState(`https://www.example.com/`);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this is where I have code that i want to 
    // run on re-render, but it won't because it stops getting updated
  }, [lookForUsername]);


  return [dashboardHref];
}
```

My test has this happening

```
// this will log false, false on first run
const { rerender, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook((lookForUsername=false, otherOption=false) => {
  console.log(lookForUsername, otherOption);
  return useMyHook(lookForUsername);
});

console.log('first re-render');
// this will make the console say true, false
rerender(true, true);

console.log('second re-render');
// console will still say true, false
rerender(false, false);

console.log('third re-render');
// console will stay true, false (so it's not just one behind)
rerender(true, true);
```

I do not understand why doing re-render with a different value updates the props in renderHook the first time, but not the subsequent times.

**NOTE**
I have updated the title & question wording to better reflect issue after more debugging

**UPDATE**
I over-simplified my example. I was originally only passing one argument in this post, but the issue was when I was passing multiple arguments

Comment: Not sure if this is working as intended or a bug so asking question to repo directly as well https://github.com/mpeyper/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/75

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to provide the answer, but if Mike Peyper posts I will mark his as the solution since he gave it to me on https://github.com/mpeyper/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/75.

To quote:

> This wont work as expected as only the first argument is passed
>   through to the hook callback. Usually you would pass an object with
>   multiple keys and destructure it in the callback:

```
const { rerender } = renderHook(({ a, b, c }) => useSomeHook(a, b, c))

rerender({ a, b, c})
```

> The reason for this is it's supposed to mimic the
>   props of the wrapping component.